Solana program that executes a function by itself
Is there anything like that ? A way for a Solana program to execute one of its function automatically, based on time/event (such as : when PDA's SOL balance exceeds an amount).
Thank you

Solana Programs must have instructions invoked in order to have a function executed. This means there must be something sending transactions to invoke this function based on time/event.
Most people in the community run permissionless cranks to accomplish this task. This can be events such as liquidations, where the person who sent the liquidation transaction gets a small portion of the overall reward.
ZetaMarkets wrote up a post on cranks if you want to learn more.
